# How can we control size of JTL file while running test from Non GUI Mode

Tags: jmeter

Is there a way by which we can control size of JTL file when Jmeter test is scheduled from NON-GUI mode.

I am running test for 100 Users, using Ramp UP 100 and duration 1200. After the test JTL file size is 170MB.[image]

I have posted Configuration in Aggregate Report Listner. I have only Aggregate listnet in my test plan.

In my jmeter.properties, i have below settings.
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml

My concern is, if i run test for longer duration (12-24 hours), then JTL file size will be huge.Kildy let me know if there is way if i can reduce amount of data getting saved in jtl file.

Comment: saving response message is not really recommended for actual load tests. uncheck it and you will observe a clear drop in file size.

Answer (score 8):

This is mostly due to storing response data (from sub results), the whole response is being written into .jtl file which causes extra disk IO and enlarges .jtl size

1. Use CSV as output format
2. Uncheck `Save Sub Results (XML)`

The relevant *user.properties* are:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
```

Example of "good" properties should look somehow like

[image: Save Service Config]

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for comprehensive explanation of your and other use cases

Comment: Thanks for the help. Let me try these configurations and i will update the thread with the results.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I just tested, my JTL file is size is reduced from 170 Mb to 5MB.

Comment: @Dmitri, really useful info. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Excellent! this helped me.. ! +1 Vote