# JMeter distributed testing - how to get aggregated report?

Tags: amazon-ec2, jmeter, distributed-testing

I have three slaves (jmeter-servers) running on EC2 instances, and in one case – (1) JMeter GUI on a local laptop, on another – same test plan (2) running from a command line on yet another EC2 instance.

In case of GUI I can see all the aggregated numbers for Throughput, 99%, etc. in – well, GUI. I'm creating a jtl file with Aggregate Report listener.

[image: aggregated data in GUI]

From watching Datadog charts monitoring the application server parameters (CPU usage, memory, etc.) I see that in case of a command line and everything on EC2 load is more than twice higher than when my local laptop is communicating with the jmeter-servers, meaning probably that the network becomes a bottleneck. So I want to run everything on EC2.

[image: Datadog, left side – all on EC2, right side - GUI on laptop]

But then – how do I get access to the same aggregated numbers when I'm running from the command line when all four machines are EC2 instances? The huge jtl file contains records for each transaction, not the aggregated one line of the entire run result.

On an attempt to download that jtl from EC2 and open it in GUI on a local laptop it generates some error instead of showing aggregated data.

Am I using a wrong listener to get to the summary data? (Tried Summary Report – it creates even larger jtl file, not the one line I'm looking for.)

Comment: Can you share the command which you use to run 'distributed test' on all 'remote servers' ?

Comment: jmeter -n -t testplan_name.jmx -Jwd=${PWD} -Jsource=source_file.csv -Juser=250 -Jratm=10 -Gremote_hosts=10.77.a.xxx,10.77.b.yyy,10.77.c.zzz -Jhost=${HOSTNAME}

Answer (score 0):

Problem in this case is not running scripts via JMeter GUI. Instead it is related to network.

I had a similar distributed setup in EC2-environment and I successfully executed heavy load tests in GUI mode. In my case, all my JMeter (master/slaves) were running on EC2 instances (windows environment). So, I will recommend you to setup your **JMeter** **(Master)** on EC2 and run scripts via GUI mode.

If you still want to run in command line mode then you simply need to pass command to create jtl file while the script runs on command line. Later on you can use this JTL to generate any JMeter report as per requirement. For more details check..

[Jmeter - Run .jmx file through command line and get the summary report in a excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537638/jmeter-run-jmx-file-through-command-line-and-get-the-summary-report-in-a-exce)

> jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test.jmx **-l /path/to/results/file.jtl**

Please refer to Dmitri answer in following question to reduce JTL size.

[How can we control size of JTL file while running test from Non GUI Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986314/how-can-we-control-size-of-jtl-file-while-running-test-from-non-gui-mode)

Comment: Yeah, I have no problems generating the jtl file (as I mentioned in the original post). But it's huge. It contains all hundreds of thousands of http requests made. And I'm looking for just aggregated one line – the one displayed in GUI. But I want to get that without involving GUI.

Comment: Aggregate figures are calculated based on statistics collected in JTL. As per my understanding you will still need all that data to calculate the aggregate figures. However to handle JTL size issue you can un-check the saving of irrelevant data. I have edited my answer to add a link which might help you in resolving size issue